# Angular Typescript CKEDITOR

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to use this `inline` mode but I am having a lot of problems with it. Some how the style is being removed and I am getting this error about `reading 'config'`. I wanted to make sure I was setting the config for this control my using the object `editor`.  Any help would be great.

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

[image]

view

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea id="indicationElementId" 
            formControlName="indicationContent" 
            class="form-control" 
            [(ngModel)]="item.ValueName"
            placeholder="Indication text"
            [class.has-error]="indicationContentNeedsErrorClass">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
CKEDITORInitializer() {
    if ((<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances.indicationElementId)
        (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances.indicationElementId.destroy(); 
        (<any>window).CKEDITOR.instances["indicationElementId"];
        let editor = (<any>window).CKEDITOR.inline("indicationElementId", {
                keystrokes: [
                    [13 /*Enter*/, 'doNothing'],
                    [(<any>window).CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 13, 'doNothing']
                ],
                enterMode: 2,
                toolbar: [
                    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'] },
                    { name: 'insert', items: ['SpecialChar'] },
                    { name: 'source', items: ['Sourcedialog'] }
                ],
                specialChars: ['&copy;', '&reg;', '&ndash;', '&frac34;', '&ge;', '&le;'],
                removeButtons: '',
                extraPlugins: 'sourcedialog'
        });

        editor.CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
        editor.CKEDITOR.config.autoParagraph = false;
        editor.CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;

        editor.on("change", () => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                this.item.ValueName = this.getContent();
                this.indicationContentChanged.next(null);
            });

        });
```

output

[image]

Comment: Can you try to use ckeditor 5.x? or are you stuck with version 4?  If you use version 5.x there are easy install instructions.  I have found that the ngx-quill editor works a bit smoother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is trying to set the config. Can try:

```
editor.config.set('allowedContent', true);
editor.config.set('autoParagraph', false);
editor.config.set('disableAutoInline', true);
```

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: editor.config.set is not a function
    at IndicationDictionaryEditDialogComponent.CKEDITORInitializer`

Comment: Sorry i didnt read "ckeditor4", can you paste the output of CKEDITOR.instances?

Comment: You mean the html that is built?

Comment: no, a console.log(CKEDITOR.instances)

Comment: I did a screen print let me know if that is not correct

Comment: any idea why I am still getting the <p> tag?

Comment: In the screenshot you can see your config, then you know how to set the config.
About getting the <p> tag what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am always getting <p>data enter </p> I don’t want the p tags in the data.

Comment: Surpose that you are refering to `config.autoParagraph = false`

Comment: has you can see from the output screen `config.autoParagraph = false`  is set but I am still getting <p> tags